# maplace.js not showing the google map

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

I followed the setup instructions on http://maplacejs.com/#Setup. 
Loaded the `maplace.js` on my server together with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>minimal maplace</title>
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry&amp;v=3.7"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/maplace-0.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    new Maplace({
        locations: [
            {
                lat: 45.9, 
                lon: 10.9,
                zoom: 8
            }
        ],
        controls_on_map: false
    }).Load(); 
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="gmap"></div>
<div id="controls"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Problem: There is no map showing up.

The html code passes the W3C validator.

The browser developer tools do not show a javascript or network error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The google map `div`

```
<div id="gmap"></div>
```

requires a size, like this for example:

```
<div id="gmap" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
```

Not working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9u1cuh2w/47/

Working demo, containing css in addition: http://jsfiddle.net/9u1cuh2w/46/

Comment: The library is changed, so let me update a current one

Comment: Indeed, maplace script is now //maplacejs.com/dist/maplace.min.js. I updated the jsfiddle demo from http://jsfiddle.net/9u1cuh2w/1/ to http://jsfiddle.net/9u1cuh2w/45/

Answer (score 0):

From [MapPlace.JS library](http://maplacejs.com/), I found this-

[image]

And the **divs** must have some **width** and **height**.

So the code should be like this-

```js
$(function() {
 new Maplace({
  locations: [
   {
    lat: 22.8167, 
    lon: 89.5500,
    zoom: 7
   }
  ],
        controls_on_map: false
 }).Load(); 
});
```

```css
#gmap {
    width: 400px; 
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry&amp;v=3.7"></script>
<script src="//maplacejs.com/dist/maplace.min.js"></script>

<div id="gmap"></div>
<div id="controls"></div>
```

### Re-

The **&key=YOUR_API_KEY** (adding a generated API key from [**here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)) part is optional. It will be needed if u use any API key needed services like finding the route, finding the distance etc.

Comment: The issue was not with the API_KEY but with the div size. This is not clear from the requirements

Comment: Yes, I had added that because someone may be confused by reading the API doc :)